# lodash : add a new field during a ._map

Tags: lodash

I have an array of objects of that type:

```
response.data = [{Name = "name1", Type = "text"}, {Name = "name2", Type = "text"}...]
```

I am trying to do add and initiate a property to all objects.

I tried:

```
   var newObj = _.map([response.data], function (value) {
               return { 
                value: "property : " + value.Name , 
                type: "my type is : " + value.Type, 
                active : false 
              };
   });
```

But it does not add the property

Do you know how to do this with lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [lodash `map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) takes in input as first argument a collection. Your `response.data` is already a collection and you are wrapping it inside another array (`[response.data]`).

To fix it, avoid to wrap it:

```
var newObj = _.map(response.data, function (value) {
    return {
        value: "property : " + value.Name,
        type: "my type is : " + value.Type,
        active: false
    };
});
```

Please, consider that [JavaScript Array natively has `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), so you do not need lodash. You can write your piece of code in the following way:

```
var newObj = response.data.map(function (value) {
    return {
        value: "property : " + value.Name,
        type: "my type is : " + value.Type,
        active: false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newObj = _.map(response.data, function (value) {
               return { 
                value: "property : " + value.Name , 
                type: "my type is : " + value.Type, 
                active : false 
              };
   });
```